# Set hls attributes in multiple outputs as seperated piece code

Tags: ffmpeg, http-live-streaming

I used this command for create multiple outputs with different qualities in hls format and I mapped the audio for those.

```
ffmpeg -i kata.mp4 -filter_complex [0:v]split=4[s0][s1][s2][s3];
[s0]scale=hd720[v0];[s1]scale=hd480[v1];[s2]scale=nhd[v2];[s3]scale=cga[v3] 
-map [v0] -map [v1] -map [v2] -map [v3] -map 0:a -c:v libx264 -c:a aac -f tee 
-hls_list_size 0 -g 48 "[select=\'v:0,a\':f=hls]out.m3u8| [select=\'v:1,a\':f=hls]out-480.m3u8| [select=\'v:2,a\':f=hls]out-360.m3u8| [select=\'v:3,a\':f=hls]out-200.m3u8"
```

in my command `-hls_list_size` not work.
I think I must be use this attribute as a seperated piece code for every outputs ,but I don't know how can I do that,Or what is the syntax code for that.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: You have to set it for each output. `...:f=hls:hls_list_size=0`

Comment: @Mulvya Thank you so much

Comment: @Mulvya How can I set `-segmet_size 10` I used `segment_size=10` but it has error

Comment: If you mean segment duration, for HLS, it is `hls_time=10`

Comment: @Mulvya yes,thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's work with using the command as this way.

```
ffmpeg -i kata.mp4 -filter_complex [0:v]split=4[s0][s1][s2][s3];
[s0]scale=hd720[v0];[s1]scale=hd480[v1];[s2]scale=nhd[v2];[s3]scale=cga[v3] 
 -map [v0] -map [v1] -map [v2] -map [v3] -map 0:a -c:v libx264 -c:a aac -f tee -g 48 -threads 0 
"[select='v\:0,a':f=hls:hls_list_size=0]../video/720p/out.m3u8|
[select='v\:1,a':f=hls:hls_list_size=0]../video/480p/out.m3u8|
[select='v\:2,a':f=hls:hls_list_size=0]../video/360p/out.m3u8|
[select='v\:3,a':f=hls:hls_list_size=0]../video/200p/out.m3u8"
```